# How to create a function that transforms each element of the list that's not numeric into as.numeric?

Tags: r

```r
list<-list(
  z= c(a=30000,b=12,c=600,d=10),

  x=c(a=30000,b=12,c=list(list(1600,1400,1400,1200)),d=list(list(10,10))))

> class(list$z)
[1] "numeric"
> class(list$x)
[1] "list"

#avoid this:
list$x$c<-as.numeric(list$x$c)
list$x$d<-as.numeric(list$x$d)
```

How to create a function that transforms each element of the list that's not numeric into as.numeric?
Attempt #1

```r
> list<-rapply(list, as.numeric, how = "replace")
> list
$z
[1] 30000    12   600    10
$x
$x$a
[1] 30000

$x$b
[1] 12
$x$c
$x$c[[1]]
[1] 1600
$x$c[[2]]
[1] 1400
$x$c[[3]]
[1] 1400
$x$c[[4]]
[1] 1200
$x$d
$x$d[[1]]
[1] 10
$x$d[[2]]
[1] 10
```

Expected output , result achieved using as.numeric() function separately:

```
list$x$c<-as.numeric(list$x$c)
list$x$d<-as.numeric(list$x$d)
> list
$z
    a     b     c     d 
30000    12   600    10 

$x
$x$a
[1] 30000

$x$b
[1] 12

$x$c
[1] 1600 1400 1400 1200

$x$d
[1] 10 10
```

is there any way to achieve the same result with a single function? Is there any way to transform it into numeric and keep the same structure?

Comment: `purrr::modify_depth()` can modify the second level not sure how to do this in one function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
library(purrr)

list <- list(
  z = c(a = 30000, b = 12, c = 600, d = 10),
  x = c(a = 30000, b = 12, c = list(list(1600, 1400, 1400, 1200)), d = list(list(10,10))))

list <- list %>% modify_depth(2, as.numeric)
list
```

Output:

```
> list
$z
    a     b     c     d 
30000    12   600    10 

$x
$x$a
[1] 30000

$x$b
[1] 12

$x$c
[1] 1600 1400 1400 1200

$x$d
[1] 10 10
```

Comment: `list$z` is not modified if you put a character vector instead.

Comment: If list$z was a character vector of characters or strings then there would be nothing to be converted to numeric. Can you give a reproducible data set if that is not what you are meaning?